# Google maps iOS SDK 1.4.0.4450 crash unrecognized selector

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

With the latest SDK on iOS 6.1.4, when a memory warning is sent out a GMSTileCoords object is apparently subscribed, but doesn't implement:

-[GMSTileCoords didReceiveMemoryWarning:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x234e80f0

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x339c72a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3b6ef97f objc_exception_throw + 31
2 CoreFoundation 0x339cae07 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 171
3 CoreFoundation 0x339c9531 ___forwarding___ + 393
4 CoreFoundation 0x33920f68 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
5 CoreFoundation 0x33918037 _CFXNotificationPost + 1427
6 Foundation 0x3422e599 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
7 Foundation 0x3423205b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 31
8 UIKit 0x35929307 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 103
```

Has anyone else seen this?  I'm at a loss on where to start besides putting a category on GMSTileCoords...

I can now recreate this in the simulator - but it does require a few events to occur before it happens.  However, when I do, it's now always in GMSIndoorState.  According to Instruments and zombie detection, it starts here:

```
-[GMSVectorMapView setIndoorEnabled:]
```

final release is here:

```
-[GMSIndoorGLTileCoordsGenerator .cxx_destruct]
```

and fails here:

```
__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0
```

I tried disabling indoor on my maps, but that hasn't helped.  Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Have not seen that yet, upgraded to 1.4.0.4450 just few days ago. Can you reproduce this in simulator? I tried to simulate memory warning in simulator (iOS6.1) while having map running, but no crash.

Comment: Also tried with     [[UIApplication sharedApplication]performSelector:@selector(_performMemoryWarning)]; while debugging on iphone with 6.1.4 but no crash either, yet.

Comment: Yes, I can recreate it in the simulator, and I'm having a real hard time nailing it down.  I'll edit above with further details.

Comment: I can also reproduce this on iPhone 6.1 Simulator using Google Maps SDK 1.4.0.4450. I'm using code very similar to the Google Maps SDK "Getting Started" guide here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start. The code I'm using to reproduce this is open-source and located here: https://github.com/asimihsan/imaptoy

Comment: Thanks Asim - I was beginning to think I was crazy.  The question is, how do we get someone at google to look at it?

Comment: Asim - could you please hit the up arrow next to this topic so hopefully it gets some attention?  Thanks

Comment: I have submitted a bug with Google - Issue 5699

Comment: The issue has been merged into https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5637 and has been confirmed by Google. But no indication yet when to be fixed. Looks like 1.3.1 (June) is free of that bug.